# Vue.js property undefined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've use this in my main component:

```
<contacts :corporation="corporation"></contacts>
```

**contacts** component:

```
export default {

    props: {
        corporation: {
            default: () => []
        }
    },

    data () {
        return {
            contacts: []
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchContacts();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchContacts() {
            console.log(this.corporation.slug); // undefined!
            CorporationService.users(this.corporation.slug)
                .then(({data}) => {
                    this.contacts = data.contacts;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch contacts in the **contacts** component. The problem is that if I `console.log(this.corporation.slug);`in the method `fetchContacts();` the `corporation.slug` is undefined!

But when I look into vue devtools the corporation prop is being set properly!

What could be going on? Already tried to change:

```
created() {
  this.fetchContacts();
}
```

to

```
mounted() {
      this.fetchContacts();
    }
```

But that's not working.

Comment: How is `corporation` variable populated in parent?

Comment: corporation: {
            default: () => [] why you are defining default as a function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use a `watch`?

Something like this.

```
watch: {
   'corporation.slug': function(slug) {
       if(slug){
          this.fetchContacts();
       }
    } 
}
```

Now if parent component changes `corporation.slug` your child component will fetch contacts automatically.

Answer (score -3):

Your prop default value is whether a value, or a function. But if it is a function, it HAS TO return something:

```
props: {
    corporation: {
        default () {
            return []
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: You definitely don't understand ES6 arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Wooops! Missed that!.. Should grab another coffee :) You are perfectly right, thank you @MU